# java: Array not Re-initializing but it's duplicating according to the user's array limit

Tags: java, arrays, menu, initialization, bluej

**this is the code I've been working on, the problem is it won't reinitialize to what I enter at menu#2 it just duplicate the array limit. if you insert a value in the array it won't remove the "0" value of the array instead it will leave the 0 alone and duplicate the array into a new one which adds a new set of lines that contains the target result. thanks for the help.**

```
`import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Arrays;

 public class Testcode
 {
  public static void main(String[] args){
  process nu = new process();
  nu.m();
  }
 }
   class process{
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
   int choice1 =0;
   int limit1;
   
   public void m(){
    System.out.println("                   ARRAY OPERATION");
    System.out.println("                        menu");
    System.out.println("                 [1] Create Array");
    System.out.println("                 [2] Insert Element");
    System.out.println("                 [3] Search");
    System.out.println("                 [4] Display");
    System.out.println("                 [5] Delete");
    System.out.println("                 [0] Stop");
    System.out.print("                 Enter choice:");
     e();
 }
    
  public void e(){
    
     //int check = 0;
    
     int array[] = new int[limit1];
    
     choice1 = in.nextInt();
     cls();
  
      if (choice1 == 1)
      {
       
        System.out.println("Create Array");
        System.out.println("Enter the limit of your array: ");
        limit1 = in.nextInt();
        
        
            if(limit1 <5){
            System.out.println("Error: Minimum limit exceeded"); 
            System.out.println("Going back to main menu");
            m(); //loop to main menu
        }
        if(limit1 >20){
            System.out.println("Error: Maximum limit exceeded");
            System.out.println("Going back to main menu");
            m(); //loop to main menu
        }
        System.out.println("An array with a limit of " + limit1 + " has been created");
        m();
   }
    
    
   if(choice1 == 2)
    {
      
      System.out.println("Enter the " + limit1 + " numbers now.");
       
      for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
       array[i] = in.nextInt();
      }
      System.out.println("You have entered the "+ limit1 + " numbers");
      m();
      
   } 
   
   if(choice1 == 4){
      
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

   }
}
 

     private void cls(){
    System.out.print('\u000C');
   }
  }    
  `
```

[Output after inserting a value inside the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ng8B.png)

Comment: You should really use `switch` instead of `if` here. And since `int` is primitive, the default value will be `0`. From `int array[] = new int[5]`, you get `array[0]=0 ....array[4]=0`. i.e. unless you assign them a value, they remain 0.

Answer (score 0):

Let's reiterate of how your program is working

1. Program starts for the first time, new instance of `process` class is created.
2. The method `m()` is called, and menu is displayed.
3. From `m()` another method `e()` is called, which creates a new `array` with limit `0` (because default value of `limit1` is 0). The value of array = `[]` - because of no elements.
4. You input a choice "1", you enter the limit now (lets say `limit1 = 6` at the moment)
5. The original array you defined above, remains unaffected. You just changed the `limit1` variable, not the array itself.
6. Now, the flow goes back to the `m()` method and MENU is displayed again.
7. You input the choice as `2` in order to enter the array elements.
8. In the method `e()` a new array is created, but with the previous value of the `limit1` i.e. 6. Therefore, `int[] array = new int[6]` is created and then you input your elements.

The problem with the code is that you are re-creating the array everytime a user inputs a choice. What you need to do is to declare the array variable in the class `process`
For example:

```
class process{
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
   int choice1 =0;
   int limit1;
   int[] array;
```

Next, in the method `e()` remove the creation of array by removing the line

```
int array[] = new int[limit1];
```

In choice 1, where you want to create the array, add the following line, when you input the limit.

```
limit1 = in.nextInt();
array = new int[limit1];
```

At this point, NOW your array is actually created only when a user presses 1.
This should fix your program.

Comment: thanks so much,what you suggested adding is missing at my original code and i switched it in switch case.

Answer (score -1):

i Think you should just initialize limit1 at the top, that might be the problem